# SED command runs from console but not through incrontab

Tags: sed, find, incron

Trying to make find and replace in a file when it is modified by the system or other user. 
Incron+SED is the combination has worked the best till this moment. Problem is when the command is put into incrontab, sed command does not work. Command works when ran from a console. Tested that trivial /bin/cp command works correcly from incron.

SED command:
`/bin/sed 's+APPLES+ORANGES+g' /bseller/salidzini.xml > /bseller/salidzini_new.xml`

INCRONTAB content: `/bseller/salidzini.xml IN_CLOSE_WRITE /bin/sed 's+APPLES+ORANGES+g' /bseller/salidzini.xml > /bseller/salidzini_new.xml`

Checked out the syslog - event is triggered and the command runs, however the salidzini_new.xml file is not being generated. sed provides no errors in syslog.

Maybe there are some characters need to be escaped? Hope that someone has some hints.

Comment: If its the same as cron I would recommend putting your command/s in a shell script then call that script outputting any (error/message) output to a script log file, something like: `/path/to/my_script.bash >> /path/to/my_script.log 2>&1` That way you can test the bash script from your cron. That way when it is run from cron any log/error output should be appended to the log file so you may be able to see see what's happening/going wrong.

Comment: Yeah the incrontab file is not like a crontab file. The latter passes your whole command to `/bin/sh` (which is how it handles things like shell redirection), whereas AFAIK incrontab just expects a single executable or script name, optionally followed by tokens like `$@` and `$#` to pass the watched path and event file to your external command if required.